# Do I need getters and setters if i'm depending on garbage collection in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory, garbage-collection

New to Cocoa and Objective-c.

Do I need getters and setters if I'm depending on garbage collection?

For example is it safe to just modify instance variables directly without the dot syntax?

And in the dealloc method can I sent them to nil instead of release (or do I even have to release them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Property (Getters and setters)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) is a mean of encapsulation, and ivar is an implementation detail.

Accessing via properties allow you to change the internal design while keeping the interface unchanged.

Whether the program has GC enabled or not, you shouldn't access ivar directly externally (internally is fine).

(Also, the `-dealloc` method is ignored if GC (not ARC) is enabled. You could implement `-finalize`. But the GC should be smart enough to clean the no-longer-needed ivars, whether to set them to `nil` or not.)

Comment: Right now I basically have one App Controller class. So in this case I shouldn't need getters and setters to modify it's own variables right?

Comment: @Chris: There no need to use properties inside the AppController class (assuming the property is @synthesize-d). But from outside, you have to use properties.

Comment: I disagree with @KennyTM's advice. While property accessors make sense for exposed (public) instance variables, I see no such justification for ivars local to the class when using ARC. Setters used to be necessary for ivars that represent objects because they take care of properly releasing previously assigned objects. But with ARC that's not necessary any more. Therefore, there's no reason for declaring local ivars as properties other than coding style preferences. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @KennyTM. Okay. But when I did read your answer, I got the impression you'd make it quite a general rule for any ivar, and that's what I was opposed to. And the question was basically: Is it safe to not use properties? And the answer is: Yes, it's safe with ARC, just not good style.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: No ARC ≠ GC. It exists only on OS X, and has been deprecated. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Garbage_collection.

Comment: @KennyTM. Ah, I was afraid of that, thanks for clarifying that. So, if anyone else reads my comments, let it be known that I was referring to ARC, the new "GC" mode introduced with Xcode 4 (IIRC). Whether the same rules applies to the older ObjC-GC, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

From within the class itself you can directly modify the private variables of course. Think about accessors mainly to expose a public interface and avoid other classes to modify directly your object. This comes from the Object Oriented Paradigm and not with the memory management.

About the release it is better to understand clearly how it works using the retain count and what have a role on that count. Some method like init increase retains the object and some other do not. A lot static methods that return new ready to use object like imageWithNamed: return an autorelease object that you have to retain explicitly to own them.

The best is to release and set to nil when you have transfer the ownership to another object (ex. an array)

ex.

```
NSString *myName   = @"zgueb";
NSArray  *myFamily = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myName, nil];
// now myName is retained by myFamily, i can release it
[myName release]; 
myName = nil;
```

Is it clear.

Vince.